# Import driver Vertica JDBC into FlyWay

Tags: jdbc, versioning, flyway, vertica

I'm looking into FlyWay 6.3 and there is no support with Vertica 9.X
There is still this issue open:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1855

Looking into the documentation I can import into the drivers directory the JDBC of Vertica.

My question is:
If I try do it by my self I'll find any problem? 
Are there still some backend problem that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Vertica 9 support was removed in 2017. Flyway won't load JDBC drivers for databases it doesn't support.

There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/2543) that re-introduces support. So you could try building Flyway from that fork.